# preg_replace and its automatic variables

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

While removing bugs from some PHP code, my browser shows me this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in (path)/functions.php on line 12
```

The line 12 of function.php is the following:

```
$file_id = preg_replace($regex,$1,$file);
```

and the regex defined by $regex is `#^([0-9]*)\.markdown$#`. I used preg_replace in other sites with the very same version of PHP (5.3). I tried to change `$1` to `\\1` or `$$1` but it did nothing.

What is the point with this code? I don't understand.

Comment: Try with quotes `"$1"` like: `$file_id = preg_replace($regex,"$1",$file);`

Comment: And… it works! Thank you Bora!

Answer (score 4):

You should use with qoutes `"$1"` like following:

```
$file_id = preg_replace($regex,"$1",$file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : use quote

```
$file_id = preg_replace($regex,'$1',$file);
```